# ¿Como saber si mi app sera rechazada o suspendida en play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Sucede que he desarrollado una aplicación con imágenes en su mayoráa diseñadas por mi, pero también he tomado algunas de internet pero etiquetadas para reutilización:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que un amigo subió una aplicación a `Play Store` que contenía una imagen con el escudo de un club de futbol (que por cierto también estaba etiquetada para reutilización) y se la suspendieron por suplantación de identidad, no sé si esa haya sido la causa de la suspensión o tal vez el nombre de su app que era muy similar al de dicho club.

Principalmente mi consulta es si hay alguna forma de saber si mi app sera aprobada o no, o en todo caso antes de subir la app demostrar que las imágenes cuentan con el permiso de reutilización.

Comment: Hola, las preguntas abiertas de este tipo no estan permitidas en SO, deben ser preguntas y respuestas concretas. Tu pregunta puede que sea votada para cerrarla. Por otro lado te recomiendo que revises la documentación que google tiene al respecto con esto.

Answer (score 0):

No existe una forma verdadera de saber si será rechazada o aprobada tu aplicación antes de subirla a la tienda, bajo tu criterio podría ser que sería aprobada pero hay varios factores como el que comentas que son las imágenes que pueden causar tu aplicación no sea aprobada, incluso la puedes subir sin problema pero posteriormente recibirías un aviso acerca de que fue rechazada, por ejemplo el rating del contenido previo llenado del formulario puede causar sea bajada de la tienda.

Pueden existir varias causas para que tu aplicación sea dada de baja 
posteriormente:

- Código malicioso.
- No llenar el cuestionario definiendo correctamente tu tipo de contenido.
- Definir incorrectamente si tu aplicación contiene publicidad.
- Reporte de uso de derechos registrados.

Lo ideal es seguir los guidelines que define Google Play:
https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/